# is it safe to enable autovacuum for a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

Am newbie in `PostgreSQL`(*Version 9.2*) Database development. While looking one of my table a saw an option called `autovaccum`.

many of my table contains 20000+ rows.For testing purpose I've altered one of that table like below

```
 ALTER TABLE theTable SET (
 autovacuum_enabled = true
 );
```

- So,I wish to know the *benefits/advantages/disadvantages(if any)* autovacuuming a table ?

Comment: I'd really like to see an answer here for Azure hosting. Apparently autovacuum is "by table only" there.

Answer (score 1):

*Autovacuum* is enabled by default in current versions of *Postgres* (and has been for a while). It's generally a good thing to have enabled for performance and other reasons.

Prior to *autovacuuming*, you would need to explicitly *vacuum* tables yourself (via *cronjobs* which executed *psql* commands to vacuum them, or similar) in order to get rid of dead tuples, etc. *Postgres* has for a while now managed this for you via *autovacuum*.

I have in some cases, with tables that have immense churn (i.e. very high rates of insertions and deletions) found it necessary to still explicitly *vacuum* via a *cron* in order to keep the *dead tuple* count low and performance high, because the *autovacuum* doesn't kick in fast enough, but this is something of a niche case.

More info: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html

Comment: which is better enabling `autovaccum` for each table or `vaccumdb` (`vacuumdb.exe -F -U postgres myDB`) ?

Comment: @keet: Depends on your situation, but in most cases autovacuum works fine. 20.000 rows is in my database an almost empty table, most tables (partitions actually) are well above 500 million records.